# Need help fixing a JavaScript regular expression error

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a JavaScript question.

I want to create a regular expression that detects a URL in a given string.  I've pasted the regular expression below.  It doesn't seem to cover all cases like google.com/index.html?2012
OR www.google.com/dir/file.aspx?isc=2012.

Any ideas on what I need to do to make it work, or perhaps a better regular expression (from somewhere else) that I can use?

```
("(^|\\s)(((http|https)(:\/\/))?(([a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]{1})+[a-zA-z0-9]+(\/{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)*\/?))", "i")
```

Comment: I added your comment to the post where it belongs.

Answer (score 1):

I use this regex and it is good for most of the cases. Original version is here http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls and i had to modify it to avoid matching multiple '.'s in the URL.

```
/\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:
(?:[^\s().]+[.]?)+|\((?:[^\s()]+|(?:\([^\s()]+\)))*\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()]+|(?:\
([^\s()]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,?«»“”‘’]))/gi
```

If you want the protocol in the beginning to be optional then use this

```
/\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)?(?:
(?:[^\s().]+[.]?)+|\((?:[^\s()]+|(?:\([^\s()]+\)))*\))+(?:\((?:[^\s()]+|(?:\
([^\s()]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,?«»“”‘’]))/gi
```

Comment: This regex works for the test cases provided as well as basic ones.  I checked it using http://regexpal.com/ .

Comment: Thanks! This detects a lot of cases that my original regular expression didn't catch.  However, it doesn't detect google.com or stanford.edu.

Comment: @LewisLin Yes...the regex needs a valid protocol in the starting. The problem with recognizing google.com is that you will end up being too liberal recognizing patterns such as abc.def etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Narenda.  Case closed!

Comment: @LewisLin check out the edited answer which handles optional protocol but it also matches abc.def  ...so it is basically a tradeoff that you want to make.